# Magento 1.9 : Get final price and discount in shopping cart

Tags: magento-1.9

I need help to obtain the following data of the shopping cart products:

- First name
- Sku
- quantity in the cart
- final price (after the discount)

I have the following code to obtain that data:

```
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
    $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
    $productSku = $item->getProduct()->getSku();
    $productQty = $item->getQty();
    $productFinalPrice = $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();
    $productAmountDiscount = $item->getProduct()->getDiscountAmount();
}
```

but when I try this code the final price and the discount returns them as null values
How can I get that data with that model?

Answer (score 0):

`discountAmount` is not a product attribute. Try `$item->getDiscountAmount()` instead.

Comment: I already try that and only get 0.00 as answer. Also i tried  $item->getFinalPrice() and  $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice() , but get the same price as              
 $item->getProduct()->getPrice().

Comment: I know that the products in the store have a discount, because after that price there is one less at the checkout. How can I get it?

Comment: how is the discount applied? using a coupon, or a special price?

Comment: a special price?